# Visual Studio - How to remove a reference in Release mode

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, release, release-management

I'm developing a library for use in other apps and this library has lots of debugging and logging statements thanks to NLog.

Is it possible to exclude the reference to NLog.dll when I switch to release mode?

Cheers,

Comment: Good question. I have an use case where I need to remove a reference in release mode.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can manually edit the csproj file, and do something like this:

```
<Reference Include="NLog" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
```

This only makes it reference that assembly in Debug. I wouldn't recommend doing this often though, because this behavior isn't reflected in the references list in Visual Studio when you change the configuration. It does work when compiling though

Comment: I think you can force VS if you unload and reload once you've switched targets.

Comment: I use this method extensively and it is very useful. Unfortunately, Visual Studio will generate a warning about the "disabled" reference. Nevertheless, this allows for very important scenarios such as referencing different files in 64-bit builds and 32-bit builds.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know is to take the reference out completely and call the assembly via reflection. Then, you should only log if the assembly loads.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good way to do this.  Unless maybe you wrote a stub reference for NLog.dll.  Since you are using the reference in your code I don't see how you could just remove it in your release.

Probably too late now but in the future you could write a class to wrap NLog.dll and then just change it in one place so it wouldn't actually log in the release version.  Or have some sort of flag.

Comment: Well if you add code in the #if DEBUG then they are excluded when compiling in Release mode

Comment: Wow, doing that on every log call sounds quite painful. I'd suggest wrapping and then using the Conditional attribute.

Answer (score -1):

There is no reason for removing a reference in case you are sure that no code will be in use from that DLL. In that case you can simply remove DLL.