# Exclude file from Visual Studio Deployment Project depending on Configuration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment, setup-deployment

I have a solution with 3 projects: windows application, class library and setup project (Visual Studio 2008). Solution has 3 configurations: Debug, Release and Release with DLL.

I want to include or exclude that DLL depending on current configuration. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260491/visual-studio-how-to-remove-a-reference-in-release-mode)

Answer (score 0):

You may find answers in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428573/managing-complex-web-config-files-between-deployment-environments).

Comment: Thanks! In that post the discussion goes about Web.config and Web Deployment. But mu issue is about simple offline setup project